# Laravel Vapor projects won't connect to database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-vapor

None of my Laravel projects deployed on Vapor will connect to my Vapor database. I get a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] error every time. To try to figure it out, I've created a fresh test project, in the same AWS region as my DB (in case that was the problem). I changed nothing in the default Laravel app except:

1. I installed Vapor CLI and Core via Composer
2. I added the DB to the vapor.yml file
3. I added a test route that queries the DB
4. on the Vapor dashboard, I changed APP_DEBUG=true to see the errors at my vanity URL

The Vapor dashboard shows that the project is connected to my database (vapor-db). Yet I still get a connection error. I tried deleting the default DB entries in the .env file. Still doesn't connect. The [Vapor docs](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/databases.html#using-databases) indicate the above is all I need to do for it to just work seamlessly, but I have been struggling with this for almost a week. Help!!

vapor.yml:

```
id: 17458
name: laravel82
environments:
    production:
        database: vapor-db
        memory: 1024
        cli-memory: 512
        runtime: php-7.4
        build:
            - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-dev'
            - 'php artisan event:cache'
            - 'npm ci && npm run prod && rm -rf node_modules'
    staging:
        database: vapor-db
        memory: 1024
        cli-memory: 512
        runtime: php-7.4
        build:
            - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install'
            - 'php artisan event:cache'
            - 'npm ci && npm run dev && rm -rf node_modules'
```

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('dbtest', function () {
    return \DB::table('images')->first();
});
```

result (staging):
https://moonlit-moscow-xdmsycwlxrhx.vapor-farm-b1.com/dbtest

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (SQL: select
* from `images` limit 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried testing to ensure database connection is working via some MySQL UI like MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that: it connects just fine from my local server (Laravel Valet) as well as TablePlus. Also, I did make some headway by creating a new Vapor DB and connecting successfully from Vapor - so it appears something might be corrupted in my main DB that Lambda doesn't like. I may just give up & move my tables to the new DB.